# php delete file from directory doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I have code like this however it doesn't delete. I check console if there is an error, no; there is no error appearing either. Can you help that can delete properly files in the pointing directory.

```
<?php

$dir    = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\phpex\uploads';

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  == 'POST' ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['filenames'] ) ) {
                foreach( $_POST['filenames'] as $key => $file ) {
                        unlink( $dir . '\\' . $file );
                }
                echo 'Files deleted';
        }
        else {
                echo 'No files selected';
        }
}

$files1 = scandir($dir);
$cnt = count($files1);
//var_dump($cnt);
echo "<h1><u> delete files from directory </u></h1>";
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
for($n=0; $n< $cnt; $n++)
{
if ( ($files1[$n])!= '.'  && $files1[$n] != '..')
        {

     print_r("<input name='filenames[]' value='".($files1[$n])."' type='checkbox' />".($files1[$n])."<br/> ");       
        }
}
echo "</br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete'>";
echo "</form>";

echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: you should also escape $dir with `\\ `

Comment: like what... can you tell me fully? @Random

Comment: like `C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\phpex\\uploads`

Comment: if you mean by changing '$dir    = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\phpex\uploads';' with '$dir    = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\phpex\\uploads'; ' it didn't work @Random

Comment: typo `$POST` forgot the underscore.

Comment: @Fred-ii- still doesnt work

Comment: @gobo can you log `$dir . '\\' . $file` ?

Comment: Do you get some kind of error? Do you have permissions required? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @user340764  it still doesn't delete + when I perform the action it causes two errors 1 ) Notice: Undefined variable: POST 2) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  both on around line 10... I don't think there is a permission problem...

Answer (score 0):

Your code of deleting is alright. It must work.
Obviously, the problem is in input: something wrong in $_POST['filenames'].
Insert log right before unlink and examine it.

Comment: This answer looks more like a comment because you didn't provide an out-of-the-box working solution.

Comment: Should I? I examined the code. In the case, that’s enough to make an answer.

Comment: What you said is entirely right. I just emmited a suggestion.